# Convert string to int and increment last digit only for build number in TFS

Tags: powershell, increment, versioning, version-numbering

I am looking for a way to convert a string 1.2.0 to an int so that I could increment the last digit. Final result should be 1.2.1

```
$values = '1.2.0'

$after = $values.split('.');

$result = [int]$after;

# TODO increment the last decimal value, result should be 1.2.3

$result
```

Answer (score 6):

Note:

- This answer focuses on *Windows PowerShell* and the `[version]` ([`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version)) type.
- For an enhanced version of function `Increment-Version` below that also supports `[semver]` ([`System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion)) - available in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only -  see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651451/45375).

---

It is surprising that the `[version]` ([`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version)) type doesn't support methods for incrementing the components of a version number (neither does the the PowerShell Core-only [`System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.semanticversion) type).

Here's a PSv5+ solution:

```bash
$versionString = '1.2.0'

$version = [version] $versionString

$versionStringIncremented = [string] [version]::new(
  $version.Major,
  $version.Minor,
  $version.Build + 1
)

# $versionStringIncremented now contains '1.2.1'
```

If you wanted to wrap that up in a **function that allows incrementing any of the components**, while setting all lower components to `0` or, in the case of `.Revision`, to undefined (reported as `-1`):

```bash
function Increment-Version {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [version] $Version
    ,
    [ValidateSet('Major', 'Minor', 'Build', 'Revision')]
    [string] $Component = 'Revision'
  )

  $useRevision = $Version.Revision -ne -1 -or $Component -eq 'Revision'

  $Major, $Minor, $Build, $Revision =
    $Version.Major, $Version.Minor, $Version.Build, $Version.Revision

  switch ($Component) {
    'Major' { $Minor = $Build = 0 }
    'Minor' { $Build = 0 }
  }

  Set-Variable $Component (1 + (Get-Variable -ValueOnly $Component))

  if ($useRevision) {
    [version]::new(
      $Major,
      $Minor,
      $Build,
      $Revision
    )
  } else {
    [version]::new(
      $Major,
      $Minor,
      $Build
    )
  }

}
```

Your command would then simplify to:

```bash
# -> '1.2.1'
$versionStringIncremented = [string] (Increment-Version 1.2.0 -Component Build)

# -> '1.3.0'
$versionStringIncremented = [string] (Increment-Version 1.2.7 -Component Minor)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This small snippet was a way to just figure out how to increment the last digit of my build number when I call the json string using tfs api.

I found a solution, I was trying to automate my TFS build version number to increment after every build during my build task. I will create variables for my build version numbers and follow this method.

I used these guides to create my script:

https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/how-to-automate-incrementing-project-build-numbers-in-vsts

http://devbraino.com/2017/09/25/auto-package-vsts-custom-build-task/

```
$first = '1'
$second = '2'
$third = '0'

$currentVersion = "$($first).$($second).$($third)"

$third = "$([System.Convert]::ToInt32($third) + 1)"
[string]$newVersionNumber = "$($first).$($second).$($third)"

$newVersionNumber
```