# Increment a version number contained in a text file

Tags: powershell, version-control, version, increment, text-processing

This self-answered question addresses the following scenario:

A version number embedded in a text file is to be incremented.

Sample text-file content:

```
nuspec{
    id = XXX;
    version: 0.0.30;
    title: XXX;
```

For instance, I want embedded version number `0.0.30` updated to `0.0.31`.

The line of interest can be assumed to match the following regex: `^\s+version: (.+);$`

Note hat the intent is not to replace the version number with a *fixed* new version, but to *increment the existing version*.

Ideally, the increment logic would handle version strings representing either `[version]` ([`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version)) or `[semver]` ([`System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion)) instances, ranging from 2 - 4 components; e.g.:

- `1.0`
- `1.0.2`
- `1.0.2.3` - `[version]` format (up to 4 numeric components)
- `1.0.2-preview2` - `[semver]` format (up to 3 numeric components), optionally with a `-`-separated preview label
- `1.0.2-preview2+001` - ditto, additionally with a `+`-separated build label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [***PowerShell (Core) 7+***](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), a concise solution for **incrementing the *last* numeric component** is possible:

```bash
# PowerShell v7+ only
$file = 'somefile.txt'
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace '(?m)(?<=^\s+version: ).+(?=;$)', {
    # Increment the *last numeric* component of the version number.
    # See below for how to target other components.
    $_.Value -replace '(?<=\.)\d+(?=$|-)', { 1 + $_.Value }
  } | Set-Content $file
```

<sup>Note:</sup>

- In PowerShell [Core] 6+, BOM-less UTF-8 is the default encoding; use `-Encoding` with `Set-Content` if you need a different encoding.
- By using `-Raw`, the command reads the entire file into memory first, which enables writing back to that same file in the same pipeline; however, there is a slight risk of data loss if writing back to the input file gets interrupted.
- `-replace` invariably replaces *all* substrings that match the regex.
- Inline regex option `(?m)` ensures that `^` and `$` match the start and end of *individual lines*, which is necessary due to `Get-Content -Raw` reading the entire file as a single, multi-line string.

Note:

- For simplicity, ***text-based* manipulation of the version string is performed**, but you could also cast `$_.Value` to `[version]` or `[semver]`  (PowerShell [Core] v6+ only) and work with that (see next section).
  The advantage of the text-based manipulation is the concise ability to retain all other components of the input version string as-is, without adding previously unspecified ones.
- The above relies on the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)'s ability to perform regex-based string substitutions fully dynamically, via a *script block* (`{ ... }`) - as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454838/45375).
- The regexes use [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) (`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`) so as to ensure that only the part of the input to be modified is matched.

  - Only the `(?<=^\s+version: )` and `(?=;$)` look-arounds are specific to the sample file format; adjust these parts as needed to match the version number in your file format.

---

To properly **increment *any* numeric component - which includes setting the *lower* version components to `0`** - more work is needed:

The most robust way is to **cast the version string to a `[version]` or `[semver]` instance**, and work with these objects.

Assuming that you have defined the `Increment-Version` function whose source code is in the bottom section, you can use the following, which increments the *minor* version-number component, for instance:

```bash
# PowerShell v7+ only
$file = 'somefile.txt'
(Get-Content -Raw $file) -replace '(?m)(?<=^\s+version: ).+(?=;$)', {
  # For [semver], use 'Major', 'Minor', or 'Patch'.
  # For [version], use 'Major', 'Minor', 'Build', or 'Revision'.
  [semver] $_.Value | Increment-Version Minor
}
```

The ***Windows PowerShell* equivalent** is the following, necessitating the direct use of `[regex]::Replace()`, because script-block-based `-replace` operations aren't supported there (note that type `[semver]` isn't available there, so `[version]` is used):

```bash
$file = 'somefile.txt'
[regex]::Replace(
  (Get-Content -Raw $file), 
  '(?m)(?<=^\s+version: ).+(?=;$)',
  {
    param($m)
    # For [semver], use 'Major', 'Minor', or 'Patch'.
    # For [version], use 'Major', 'Minor', 'Build', or 'Revision'.
    [version] $m.Value | Increment-Version Minor
  }
)
```

---

**`Increment-Version` source code:**

- See the comment-based help embedded in the source code for details.

```bash
function Increment-Version {
  <#
.SYNOPSIS
  Increments the specified component of a given version number.
.DESCRIPTION
  Operates on either [semver] or [version] version-number objects and increments
  the specified numeric component, setting all lower components to 0.

  If you don't specify a target -Component, the smallest type-appropriate
  numeric component is used: 'Patch' for [semver], 'Revision' for [version].
  
  -Component Revision is specific to [version], -Component Patch and
  -Component Build can be used interchangeably to refer to the 3rd component.

  Simpy pipe to | ForEach-Object ToString to convert the output objects to
  version *strings*.

  Note:
   * If you don't supply [semver] or [version] instances as input, they input
     objects are converted as follows:
      * If [semver] is available, an attempt to convert to [semver] is made first.
      * If [semver] isn't available or conversion failed or 'Revision' is
        specified as the target component, conversion to [version] is attempted.
      * To avoid ambiguity, provide [semver] or [version] instances as input.
   * The 'Revision' -Component value applies to [version] instances only.
     The 'Patch' and 'Build' values can be used interchangeably to target the
     3rd component of either type.
   * For [semver], if a prerelease and/or build label is present, it is kept as-is.
   * For [version], missing build and revision numbers are retained as such,
     if possible, so that the stringified version of the output object retains 
     its format.
  
.NOTES
  "Increment" is not an approved verb, but it is used nonetheless, because
  none of the approved verbs can express the operation's intent succinctly.
.EXAMPLE
  '1.0' | Increment-Version Minor

  Outputs the equivalent of [semver] '1.1.0', if [semver] is available,
  otherwise the equivalent of [version] '1.1'

.EXAMPLE
  '1.0' | Increment-Version Revision

  Outputs the equivalent of [version] '1.0.0.1'

.EXAMPLE
  '1.0.2-releaseX+buildY' | Increment-Version Minor

  Outputs the equivalent of [semver] '1.1.0-releaseX+buildY'

.EXAMPLE
  [version ] '1.0' | Increment-Version | ForEach-Object ToString

  Outputs '1.0.0.1', i.e. the equivalent of ([version] '1.0.0.1').ToString()
#>
  param(
    # Note: 'Patch' and 'Build' can be used interchangeably to refer to the 3rd component.
    #       'Revision' applies to [version] only
    [ValidateSet('Major', 'Minor', 'Patch', 'Build', 'Revision')] [string] $Component,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [object] $Version
  )

  begin {
    Set-StrictMode -Version 1
    $haveSemVer = $null -ne ('semver' -as [type])
  }

  process {
    $semVer = $null
    if ($haveSemVer -and ($Version -is [semver])) {
      $semVer = $Version
    }
    elseif ($Version -isnot [version]) {
      # Try interpretation as a [semver] first.
      if ($haveSemVer -and $Component -ne 'Revision') { $semVer = $Version -as [semver] }
      # Fall back to [version]
      if (-not $semVer) {
        $Version = [version] "$Version"
        if (-not $?) { return } # If interpretation as [version] fails, give up.
      }
    }

    if ($semVer) {
      # [semver]
      if ($Component -eq 'Revision') { Write-Error "[semver] instances don't have a 'Revision' component"; return }

      $newNumericComponents = switch ($Component) {
        'Major' { (1 + $semVer.Major), 0, 0 }
        'Minor' { $semVer.Major, (1 + $semVer.Minor), 0 }
        # $null (default), 'Patch' == 'Build'
        Default { $semVer.Major, $semVer.Minor, (1 + $semVer.Patch) } 
      }
  
      [semver]::new(
        $newNumericComponents[0],
        $newNumericComponents[1],
        $newNumericComponents[2],
        $semVer.PreReleaseLabel,
        $semVer.BuildLabel
      )
    
    }
    else {
      # [version]
      if ($Component -eq 'Patch') { $Component = 'Build' }
      $newComponents = switch ($Component) {
        'Major' { (1 + $Version.Major), 0 }
        'Minor' { $Version.Major, (1 + $Version.Minor) }
        'Build' { $Version.Major, $Version.Minor, (1 + [Math]::Max(0, $Version.Build)) }
        # $null (default), 'Revision'
        Default { $Version.Major, $Version.Minor, [Math]::Max(0, $Version.Build), (1 + [Math]::Max(0, $Version.Revision)) } 
      }
      if ($newComponents.Count -eq 2 -and $Version.Build -ne -1) {
        $newComponents += 0
      }
      if ($newComponents.Count -eq 3 -and $Version.Revision -ne -1) {
        $newComponents += 0
      }

      [version]::new.Invoke($newComponents)
    }

  }

}
```